# Is it possible to assign color gradients to NetworkX edges

Tags: networkx

So, if node A is red and node B is blue, is it possible to set the edge between them to be a color gradient from red to blue?

Comment: `Networkx` is internally using `LineCollection` from `matplotlib` to draw the edges, [see here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_edges), which as far as I've found don't directly support multiple colors. However, as in this [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) you could split each edge and draw multiple segments for each line.

Comment: @tewerty, i would be interested if you found a way to implement this!

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a co-occurrence graph where I color the node clusters similarly, and I wanted a color gradient for edges connecting two groups. It is a little bit messy and there is surely a more elegant way to proceed, but at least it does the job for me. Below I worked around the limitation of matplotlib by essentially cutting relevant edges into small pieces:

1- creating dummy invisible nodes between the nodes of interest

2- connecting those nodes with a small edges constituting a segment of the edge to replace and with a color interpolated between the colors of the two connected nodes

3- removing the edge to be replaced by edge segments

The result script is below and includes some small things to fuse desired nodes, or tune the threshold at which a node is displayed on the graph. It reads an excel spreadsheet where a column is provided with a list of carriage return separated keywords in each cell.

```py
# Draws co-occurrence graph colored by community clustering


import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from community import community_louvain  # Install with: pip install python-louvain
import math
import json
import numpy as np

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

'''list of fused nodes'''
fusion_reference = {
    'foo':'bar',
    'bip':'bob'
}  # If you want to fuse nodes

'''list of allowed individual words among keywords'''
allowed_words = ['blob', 'plop'] #if you want to include individual words from node labels

'''threshold for displaying nodes'''
thres = 5

'''number of steps for gradient'''
num_steps = 100

# Function to extract individual words from phrases and lemmatize
def extract_and_lemmatize(keywords_list, allowed_words):
    for i, keywords in enumerate(keywords_list):
        words = [word.strip() for keyword in keywords.split('\n') for word in keyword.split()]
        lemmatized_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words]
        selected_words = [word for word in lemmatized_words if word in allowed_words]
        keywords_list[i] = keywords_list[i] + "\n" + "\n".join(selected_words)

        keywords_list[i] = [keyword.lower().strip() for keyword in keywords_list[i].split('\n')]

    return keywords_list

# Function to interpolate the position of the dummy nodes
def interpolate_positions(start_pos, end_pos, num_steps):
    x_values = np.linspace(start_pos[0], end_pos[0], num_steps)
    y_values = np.linspace(start_pos[1], end_pos[1], num_steps)
    return zip(x_values, y_values)


# Read the Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('keywords.xlsx')

# Extract keywords and lemmatize individual words
keywords_list = df['Keywords'].dropna()

keywords_list = extract_and_lemmatize(keywords_list, allowed_words)

# Modify keyword lists based on the reference dictionary
for i, keywords in enumerate(keywords_list):
    for old_label, new_label in fusion_reference.items():
        keywords_list[i] = [new_label if keyword.lower().strip() == old_label.lower().strip() else keyword for keyword in
                            keywords_list[i]]
all_words = [keyword for sublist in keywords_list for keyword in sublist]


# Generate a co-occurrence graph
G = nx.Graph()

# Add nodes to the graph for individual words
for word in set(all_words):
    count = all_words.count(word)

    if count >= thres and word.strip():  # Threshold for nodes
        G.add_node(word, size=count)
        print(word, count)
        
# Add edges to the graph based on co-occurrence
for keywords in keywords_list:
    for word1 in keywords:
        for word2 in keywords:
            if word1 != word2:
                if all_words.count(word1) >= thres and all_words.count(word2) >= thres:
                    if G.has_edge(word1, word2):
                        G[word1][word2]['weight'] += 0.2
                    else:
                        G.add_edge(word1, word2, weight=1)

# Filter out isolated nodes
isolated_nodes = [node for node in G.nodes if G.degree(node) == 0]
G.remove_nodes_from(isolated_nodes)

# Remove nodes with empty labels
empty_label_nodes = [node for node in G.nodes if not G.nodes[node].get('size', 0) and not node.strip()]
G.remove_nodes_from(empty_label_nodes)

# Display the graph with colorized clusters
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # Updated layout for better visualization

# Set of nodes to label
labels = {}

# Community detection (Louvain method) with resolution parameter
partition = community_louvain.best_partition(G)  # Adjust resolution as needed

initial_color_vector = list(partition.values())
alpha_vector         = np.ones(len(G.nodes))


# Lists to store nodes and edges to be added
nodes_to_add = []
edges_to_add = []
original_edges_involved = []  # List to keep track of original edges involved in the color gradient

#list of node labels as I don't want the names of the dummy nodes to appear on the graph so the node name is not the node label
for node in G.nodes:
    labels[node] = node

# Loop over the edges and print node pairs
for edge in G.edges:
    # print("Edge:", edge)
    node1, node2 = edge
    weight       = G[node1][node2]["weight"]
    # print("Nodes:", node1, node2)
    if partition[node1] != partition[node2]:
        original_edges_involved.append((node1, node2))
        # Interpolate positions between node1 and node2
        positions = list(interpolate_positions(pos[node1], pos[node2], num_steps))

        # Create nodes and edges along the interpolated positions
        last_node = node1
        for i, position in enumerate(positions[1:]):  # Start from the second position
            new_node = "interp" + "_" + node1 + "_" + node2 + "_" + str(i)  # Generate a new node ID
            labels[new_node] = " "
            nodes_to_add.append((new_node, {'position': position, 'size': thres}))
            pos[new_node] = np.array(position)
            edges_to_add.append((last_node, new_node, {'weight': weight}))
            last_node = new_node  # Update the last node
            initial_color_vector.append(0.5) #this is just a placeholder as those nodes are set as invisible
            alpha_vector = np.append(alpha_vector,0.0)
        # Connect the last created node directly to node2
        edges_to_add.append((last_node, node2, {'weight': weight}))
        
# Add the collected nodes and edges to the graph
G.add_nodes_from(nodes_to_add)
G.add_edges_from(edges_to_add)

# Remove the original edges involved in the color gradient
G.remove_edges_from(original_edges_involved)

# Calculate an offset for label positioning based on the square root of node size
label_offset = {node: (0, -0.02 - 0.01 * math.sqrt(G.nodes[node].get('size', 1))) for node in
                G.nodes if G.nodes[node].get('size', 0) >= thres}

# Combine the label offsets with the node positions
pos_labels = {k: (x + label_offset[k][0], y + label_offset[k][1]) for k, (x, y) in pos.items()}

node_sizes = [G.nodes[node].get('size', 0) * 10 for node in G.nodes if G.nodes[node].get('size', 0) >= thres]
edge_widths = [G[u][v]['weight'] for u, v in G.edges]

# Convert node_sizes to float
node_sizes_scalar = [float(size) for size in node_sizes]

# Draw nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=node_sizes_scalar, node_color=initial_color_vector, alpha=alpha_vector)
                      
# Configure coloring of edges
colormap = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis')

edge_colors = []

for u, v in G.edges: 
    if u in partition and v in partition: # Edges with both nodes in the partition are within-group edges and so they have a single color 
        color_u = colormap(partition[u] / max(partition.values()))
        edge_colors.append(color_u)
    else:
        #we infer which nodes a segment connects from the nodes' created names.
        words1 = u.split("_") 
        words2 = v.split("_")
        if len(words1)>len(words2):
            words = words1
        else:
            words = words2
        node1 = words[1]
        node2 = words[2]
        
        #we infer where we are on the line from the rank that is also recorded in the created name
        rank = int(words[3])
        color_u = partition[node1] / max(partition.values())
        color_v = partition[node2] / max(partition.values())
        
        #color is interpolation between the two groups
        grad    = rank / (num_steps - 1)
        color = colormap((1-grad)*color_u + grad * color_v)
        edge_colors.append(color)
    
# Draw edges and labels

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=edge_widths, edge_color=edge_colors, alpha=0.5)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos_labels, labels=labels, font_size=20)

# Display the graph
plt.show()

# Convert NumPy arrays to lists in the pos dictionary
pos = {k: v.tolist() for k, v in pos.items()}

# Save relevant data to reproduce the graph to a text file

graph_data = {
    'nodes': [(n, G.nodes[n]) for n in G.nodes],
    'edges': [(u, v, G[u][v]) for u, v in G.edges],
    'partition': partition,
    'node_sizes': node_sizes_scalar,
    'node_colors': initial_color_vector,
    'node_alphas': alpha_vector.tolist(),
    'edge_widths': edge_widths,
    'edge_colors': edge_colors,
    'pos': pos,
    'pos_labels': pos_labels,
    'labels':labels
}

with open('graph_data.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(graph_data, json_file)
```

This little script below allows to load a graph from data saved in the .json file generated from the other script:

```py
    import sys
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import json
    
    def display_saved_graph(json_file):
        # Load graph data from the specified .json file
        with open(json_file, 'r') as json_file:
            graph_data = json.load(json_file)
    
        # Create a graph and add nodes and edges
        G = nx.Graph()
        G.add_nodes_from(graph_data['nodes'])
        G.add_edges_from(graph_data['edges'])
    
        # Display the graph with colorized clusters
        pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # Use the layout from the saved data
    
        # Convert the position data to NumPy arrays
        pos = {k: v if isinstance(v, list) else v for k, v in graph_data['pos'].items()}
    
        # Calculate an offset for label positioning based on the square root of node size
        label_offset = {node: (0, -0.02 - 0.01 * (node_size / 10)**0.5) for node, node_size in zip(G.nodes, graph_data['node_sizes'])}
    
        # Combine the label offsets with the node positions
        pos_labels = {k: (x + label_offset[k][0], y + label_offset[k][1]) for k, (x, y) in pos.items()}
    
        # Draw nodes and edges with colorized clusters
        nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=graph_data['node_sizes'], node_color=graph_data['node_colors'], alpha=graph_data['node_alphas'])
        nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=graph_data['edge_widths'], edge_color=graph_data['edge_colors'], alpha=0.5)
        nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos_labels, labels=graph_data['labels'],font_size=20)
    
        # Display the graph
        plt.show()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        if len(sys.argv) != 2:
            print("Usage: python display_saved_graph.py <json_file>")
            sys.exit(1)
    
        json_file = sys.argv[1]
        display_saved_graph(json_file)
```

Hope it helps,
Best regards.